# TensorFlow Object Distance Detection

Tags: android, tensorflow-lite

I want to calculate the distance of detected Object using TensorFlow lite. And to calculate distance, I am using

- Focal Length: 4.42mm
- Real Height of object: 1620mm
- Camera frame Height: 696px
- Image Height: 228px
- Sensor height: 3.42mm

**distance = (4.42mm * 1620mm * 696px) / (228px * 3.42mm)**

Please help me whether TensorFlow provides a distance of detect objects

Answer (score 0):

You may use detected object height/width and compare it to real object height/width. You would need some baseline of what the mapping is expected to be using a formula or photos you have taken.